# Are there any campaign resources for Blue Planet v2?

Tags: online-resources

Are there any online resources for BPv2 regarding adventures and campaigns?

- **Downloadable adventures** (official or not)
- **Blogs** (campaign specific house-rules, custom-created equipment/creatures/npcs, ...)
- **Campaign logs** (experience about running a longer BPv2 campaign, handling of combat situations, ...)
- **Discussion forums** (discussion of anything meta-plot and mechanic related, as well as any previously mentioned topics)
- **...**

I'd be especially interested in anything that builds on the various **[Access Denied]** sidebars from some of the rule books, expanding these text snippets into adventures/campaigns.

Comment: I have posted some BP story seeds on my site, but as we do not ever play it, they are few and far between. I was pleased to see a Blue Planet question!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not a BP player nor GM. However, a quick google turns up:

The new [publisher's website, Redbrick Ltd.](http://www.redbrick-limited.com/cms/index.php?categoryid=20). Includes forums.

[Dark Water Fansite](http://seahawk.110mb.com/game-links.php)

[RPG Resource Blue Planet pages](http://www.rpg-resource.org.uk/index.php?article=65&visual=6)

[Blue Dive Blue Planet pages](http://www.bluedive.nl/?/bp/)

[RPGGeek Blue  Planet pages](http://rpggeek.com/rpgfamily/325/blue-planet) - includes forums.

Comment: Thanks for the links, although I have hoped that BP was at least a little more popular around here and that somebody would unearth a secret awesome jewel of stuff for the system. ^^

Comment: I was hoping my Google-Fu would crit-hit... but, alas, it didn't, and I'm no fan of it myself. (I've read 1E, but didn't find it particularly cogent...)